# Grub won't open after dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I dual-booted Ubuntu 18.04 with windows10. But upon switching my laptop, I don't get grub menu. Windows opens directly. And if I go to boot menu, then select Ubuntu, Ubuntu opens. I have a HP laptop.

Please give suggestions, what can i do?

Comment: From Ubuntu, in the terminal, run `sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64`. And make sure **secure boot** is disabled (in the BIOS menu).

Comment: Have you changed boot priority?

Comment: I tried sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64. But it didn't work.

Comment: how to change boot priority?